# NCurses-Like System for Windows

Tags: c++, ncurses

Are there any C++ libraries similar to Ncurses, but for Windows? It seems there are no ports of Ncurses and I need a really good display system like it.

Any suggestions? Cross-platform is a plus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is very similar library PDCurses. It uses the same calls as ncurses, but works on Win32. The only thing you'd need to port a program would be to recompile.

http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Not cross platform, but you could use the [Windows API's Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073(VS.85).aspx) directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the GNUWin32 project provides a direct port of NCurses.

See here:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm

Comment: The [ncurses](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm) page appears to be an error.  The [packages](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) page shows [PDcurses](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pdcurses.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [CYGWIN](http://www.cygwin.com/) with NCURSES: curses + crossplatforms, as you want.

Other than that, you can try Borland's old CONIO (there is a repository of old Borland Software at Embarcadero), or Microsoft's [Win32 API Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Does the cygwin solution force the user to install cygwin though?

Comment: @Billy As far as I'm aware, yes, you need the cygwin DLL. The PDCurses solution is a much better bet - I've played with it, and it works well - no cygwin required,

Comment: @Bill: you need only the cygwin DLL.

Comment: @Dan Andreatta: Does that mean I can just redistribute the DLL with my application in a self extracting ZIP? Or does that chain me to GPL fun?

Comment: @Billy: GPL fun. You can freely link against the dll if you distribute your application with an open source licence, in which case you simply have to distribute the source code of the dll. Otherwise you have to purchase a license from RedHat.

Comment: @Dan Andreatta: Grr. Getting difficult to stick to the BSD license. :P Thanks!

Comment: @Billy: If I read it correctly, you can distribute your code with a BSD license together with the DLL, which remain under the "extended GPLv2".

Answer (score 0):

[SetEdit](http://setedit.sourceforge.net/) uses a port of Borland's TurboVision. This port is cross platform and can be found [here](http://tvision.sourceforge.net/), licensed under GPL.