# Cross-platform way of having non-blocking console input

Tags: c++, c, input, console, cross-platform

I need a crossplatform way of calling std::cin in non blocking way. I know it's possible with threads, but maybe there is a better option? Threds seem to be overkill for this.

Comment: AFAIR [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) provides such feature. But I'm not sure what's more _'overkill'_, depends on definition.

Comment: I know ncurses, but unfortunatelly I need cross platform solution.

Comment: Have you looked into the readsome function?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/readsome/

Comment: There are several platforms supported by ncurses. What platform do you have actually?

Comment: Windows and linux, I think its only for posix.

Comment: Check this out for Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713698/ncurses-like-system-for-windows

Comment: Oh, that's good. And readsome looks good, however does it ignore white characters?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan `readsome` usually only returns the number of characters already in the buffer, and so is useless for this.

Comment: @user1873947 OT: You should address your comments responses (type '@')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard C and C++ do not provide any means to do non blocking I/O. Typically, the C and C++ runtime environment does not see any input at all until the user has pressed the `<ENTER>` key.

So, the only options are really to use a separate thread to read the input, or to use platform-specific methods to do the non-blocking input (possibly wrapped so you can easily replace that part when porting to a different platform. Libraries like `ncurses` provide these input methods pre-wrapped for a number of platforms).

Comment: There are "ncurses" and similar libraries available for several different platforms, which contains code to deal with "get key without blocking" and other similar things.