# How do I Display Something in the Exact Middle of the Display Screen?

Tags: c++

I'm looking to add something exciting to my final project this semester. I'm trying to create a text-based combat game and I'm using a round counter for each attack.  I want the round counter to display in the middle both vertically and horizontally of a blank screen between rounds.  I know how to clear the screen, but how do I display it in the center? I thought of using

```
cout << "                  Round 1                    ";
```

but in order for that to display in the middle, the only thing I know how to do is to add like, 20 lines of

```
cout << endl;
```

Please help me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  It looks all official now.

Comment: Using `cout` is not approprate for such output. Take a look at the [ncurses library](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to keep your game in the console window, [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) allows you to set where you'd like to print.

You are also given the option of some GUI stuff like menus, message boxes, etc.

Others have posted similar solutions to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980361/how-to-align-output-to-center-of-screen-c).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I love how fast the people on these forums are.

Comment: @NateCowley, Stackoverflow is not a forum. :P Also, please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information about Stackoverflow not being a forum.  I would've accepted the answer earlier, but it said I had to wait a little while and I got distracted trying to implement your answer into my code.