# How to create a pull-down menus in C with ASCII?

Tags: c, windows, menu, mingw32

As some DOS application, how to display a pull-down menus in C with ASCII?

(and can be controlled by arrow keys)

like this:

```
+--------------------              +--------------------
| File | Edit | Help ...           | File | Edit | Help ...
+----------+---------              +------+----------+--
| New (N)  |                              | Cut (X)  |
| Open (O) |               AND            | Copy (C) |
| Save (S) |                              | Undo (U) |
+----------+                              +----------+
```

Which library can I use?

Comment: Think about `printf` :)

Comment: @haccks Do everything myself without libs? Heavy stuff :-(

Comment: These tables seems like that of SQL, I think you should see some SQL source code  for creating the table. I guess there must be something useful.

Comment: Take a look at [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) or [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: @Kninnug Great! This is actually what I am looking for.

Comment: If this is a DOS application, with a 16-bit compiler and everything, you're probably using a Borland C or Pascal compiler. Look into Turbo Vision, a very famous library (I'm showing my age here) for creating UIs in DOS. There is [a modern port here](http://tvision.sourceforge.net/) which also includes a link to the original source. If it's modern Windows, use the port, since it's a famous and well-designed library with high-level classes. There are [menus and submenus](http://www.sigala.it/sergio/tvision/html/classTMenu.html), for example, exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a library like ncurses. Doing this from scratch is pretty tough, but, if you really want, you need to use a lot of printf's and functions to write a character at a certain position.

Here you will find more ncurses alternatives for windows: [NCurses-Like System for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713698/ncurses-like-system-for-windows)